# iOS Attributed Text Setting Entire String on Editing End

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Swift 3.0. I'm highlighting certain words in a UITextField using attributed text.

```
let myRegex = "2 highlight"
for match in myRegex.matches(in: textField.text!, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: textField.text!.utf16.count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
   attributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
}
textField.attributedText = attributedString
```

For some reason though, once I get over a certain character limit, once I leave the text field, the entire thing gets highlighted. There is no way to unhighlight it once this happens.

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3o6ZthPnWEvD7v5wT6

I've got nothing in my code that does anything like this, why is the whole string being attributed once I leave the field?

Comment: Can you show how does `myRegex` look like?

Comment: updated the question with `myRegex`. I experience the same behavior even with a simple regex expression like shown.

Comment: it's a string not regular expression, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's a much more complicated regex string than in the example but it is a string. It's a string in pcre (php) flavor as shown on regex101.com.

Comment: Internals of an attributed string might kick in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/ChangingAttrStrings.html May be try starting from a clean attributed string on each char edit?